# Residue of $ze^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

I want to calculate the residue of $ze^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$ at $z=1$. My idea is the following:

$$
ze^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=((z-1)+1)e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=(z-1)e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}+e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}
$$

Around $z=1$:

$$
e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=1+(z-1)^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}(z-1)^{-2}+...
$$

Thus:

$$
(z-1)e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=(z-1)+1+\frac{1}{2}(z-1)^{-1}+...
$$

Therefore:

$$
ze^{\frac{1}{z-1}} = e^{\frac{1}{z-1}} + (z-1)e^{\frac{1}{z-1}} = (z-1)+2+\frac{3}
{2}(z-1)^{-1}+...
$$

I want to see if the idea is correct

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Correct. Same result, e.g, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1643327/42969